# Writing mathematical expression in a file

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation, output

I am trying to write a mathematical expression as `variable = expression` in the output file.

The current method that I am doing is through `WriteString` as

```
expr = -((a*b*y^2*(-1 + z)*z*(1 + a*b + z))/(1 + a*b)^2) +
        (z*(1 + a*b - a*b*z + (z + a*b*z)^2))/(1 + a*b)^2 -
        (y*z*((-1 + z)^2 + a*b*(2 - 3*z + z^2) + a^2*b^2*(1 - z + z^2)))/(1 + a*b)^2
expression = CForm[expr] /. {Power->pow};
(*expression = CForm[HornerForm[expr]] /. {Power->pow};*)
str=OpenWrite["output.hh"];
WriteString[str," double variable = ", expression,";"];
(*WriteString[str," double variable = ", ExportString[expression,"Text"]];*)
Close[str];
```

The output is

```
 cat output.hh
 double variable = -(a*b*(-1 + z)*z*(1 + a*b + z)*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*pow(y,2)) - y*z*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*(pow(-1 + z,2) + a*b*(2 - 3*z + pow(z,2)) + pow(a,2)*pow(b,2)*(1 - z + pow(z,2))) + z*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*(1 + a*b - a*b*z + pow(z + a*b*z,2));
```

I want to break the line as the original `expr` (or after some user-specified column say 80) i.e.

```
 double variable = -(a*b*(-1 + z)*z*(1 + a*b + z)*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*pow(y,2)) -
                   y*z*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*(pow(-1 + z,2) + a*b*(2 - 3*z + pow(z,2)) + pow(a,2)*pow(b,2)*(1 - z + pow(z,2))) + 
                   z*pow(1 + a*b,-2)*(1 + a*b - a*b*z + pow(z + a*b*z,2));
```

Although this might not lead to optimized expression for numerical evaluation, however it is wanted as beautification.
Also how should one optimize expression for further processing to other languages. Any suggestion?  `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` and `HornerForm` are some options. Any other recommendation? `MathCode` is much costly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) as follows:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power, CForm] := pow
Protect[Power];

Format[unquotedString[s_], CForm] := Format[s, OutputForm]
```

Then:

```
With[{e = expr},
    ToString[HoldForm[unquotedString["double variable"] = e], CForm, PageWidth->80]
]

"double variable = 
   -((a*b*pow(y,2)*(-1 + z)*z*(1 + a*b + z))/pow(1 + a*b,2)) + 
    (z*(1 + a*b - a*b*z + pow(z + a*b*z,2)))/pow(1 + a*b,2) - 
    (y*z*(pow(-1 + z,2) + a*b*(2 - 3*z + pow(z,2)) + 
         pow(a,2)*pow(b,2)*(1 - z + pow(z,2))))/pow(1 + a*b,2)"
```

The [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) is needed so that the [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) (=) doesn't evaluate, and the `unquotedString` function allows inserting explicit strings without quotes.

Comment: Thanks. But If I save this in a text file then newline characters `\n` appears.  `PageWidth` is only for Notebook display or it can be incorporated to the content of output file which is also I wanted. Like the expression inside the output file will have 80 column limit for a line.

Comment: Now this works well with `WriteString`. Thanks